# gcov yields 0 coverage but unit tests run just fine

Tags: c, gcov

I wrote about 8 unit tests for a code and for some of them, the gcov coverage is consistent with the unit test coverage (showing that all the blocks have been executed, etc). For the rest, gcov looks like this:

```
function XXX called 0 returned 0% blocks executed 0%
```

but my unit test looks this:

```
Lines executed:80.00% of 10
Branches executed:100.00% of 8
Taken at least once:75.00% of 8
No calls
```

I'm confused because it shows some lines in the function are executed, but gcov tells me otherwise. Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To describe the problem in a bit more detail, in case someone else runs into the same problem, I was running unit tests and I knew the unit tests were fine, and everything seemed to be compiling just fine, but somehow I was getting 0 coverage.

It turns out that my makefile was doing something funny.  I had this block in my makefile that looked like this:

```
unittestresults.out: 
    gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Wall -lm -std=c99 -o unittest1 -g unittest1.c dominion.o rngs.o
    gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Wall -lm -std=c99 -o unittest2 -g unittest2.c dominion.o rngs.o
    gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Wall -lm -std=c99 -o unittest3 -g unittest3.c dominion.o rngs.o
    gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Wall -lm -std=c99 -o unittest4 -g unittest4.c dominion.o rngs.o
    gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Wall -lm -std=c99 -o cardtest1 -g cardtest1.c dominion.o rngs.o
    gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Wall -lm -std=c99 -o cardtest2 -g cardtest2.c dominion.o rngs.o
    gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Wall -lm -std=c99 -o cardtest3 -g cardtest3.c dominion.o rngs.o
    gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Wall -lm -std=c99 -o cardtest4 -g cardtest4.c dominion.o rngs.o
    ./unittest1 &> unittestresult.out
    ./unittest2 >> unittestresult.out
    ./unittest3 >> unittestresult.out
    ./unittest4 >> unittestresult.out
    ./cardtest1 >> unittestresult.out
    ./cardtest2 >> unittestresult.out
    ./cardtest3 >> unittestresult.out
    ./cardtest4 >> unittestresult.out
    gcov -b dominion.c >> unittestresult.out
    cat dominion.c.gcov >> unittestresult.out
```

I ended up changing the first line to this and that fixed everything.  Using the same unit tests, I now get coverage:

```
unittestresults.out: unittest1.c unittest2.c unittest3.c unittest4.c cardtest1.c cardtest2.c cardtest3.c cardtest4.c dominion.o rngs.o
```